# Showing a thin line betwen cardview items

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, cardview

[image]

As above screenshot you can see number of item cover by cardview,but question is card view contain thin between two item

How can i remove this thin line, my cardview xml property is

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
        card_view:cardElevation="10dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: That is not a line, it's just the shadow shown below the cards because of elevation

Comment: also attach your row.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
card_view:cardElevation="10dp"
```

to this:

```
card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to decrease the card elevation. Change the code as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
        card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```